# AWS CognitoSync package cannot be used in Xamarin .NET Standard project

Tags: amazon-web-services, xamarin, xamarin.forms, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am trying to integrate the AWS Cognito Sync functionalities in the .NET Standard Library Project of my Xamarin.Forms app.
I installed the AWS Core Runtime, AWS Cognito Sync and AWS Cognito Identity packages with NuGet, they are present in the Dependencies of my project and I'm able to see and use classes from AWS Core and Cognito Identity but I cannot use any class (like CognitoSyncManager) from the AWS Cognito Sync package.

```
CognitoAWSCredentials credentials = new CognitoAWSCredentials 
    ("AWS_IDENTITY_POOL_ID", RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
    //CognitoAWSCredentials is fine

CognitoSyncManager syncManager = new CognitoSyncManager (
    credentials,
    new AmazonCognitoSyncConfig {
        RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUWest1
    }
);
//CognitoSyncManager does not exist
```

This is the .csproj:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.CognitoIdentity" Version="3.3.2.17" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.CognitoSync" Version="3.3.1.26" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Core" Version="3.3.21" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="2.5.0.121934" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Contact AWS technical support and ask them to provide a .NET Standard compliant release. You would not find any way to solve this. Of course, AWS current release seems to support most platforms, so you only need to avoid using it in .NET Standard projects.